# how do i get a String from firebase on android studio?

Tags: android, firebase

I am new at using firebase and I don't understand how to get a single String from my database

my database

[image]

I want to write a function that gets the User ID and returns his name. I tried many things but nothing worked out. Can someone give me this function or telling me how to write it?

This is what I tried:

```
public void checkFunction() {

  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();  
  DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child("0");  

  ValueEventListener UserFromID = new ValueEventListener() {  

    @Override  
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {  
      return dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

  };

  myRef.addValueEventListener(UserFromID);
}
```

But I get the following error

> Cannot return a value from a method with void result type

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried

Comment: Which is the User Id?

Comment: The user Id is the name of the child, and his value is his name. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

Ideally we'd need to know more about what you are trying to do.

Should the user of the app have access to all those User IDs? or should they have access to only their own? Are they an admin, or an end user etc?

When you say "*a function that gets the User ID*", do you mean YOU are providing the ID, and the function returns the name of the person within that user ID? Also, you are hard-coding the user ID of **0** in this case. Is this just for testing?
Are you using Firebase Auth for user registrations etc, or no registrations?

It's hard to answer the question without knowing more, but lets assume a user whats to get any string from Firebase that they have access to.
(If using Firebase Auth, then the DatabaseReference is slightly different)

So you'll need a DatabaseReference that maps to the correct node in the tree. In your example, the user would not be able to access the users 1 and 2. (is this what you want?). In my example, they can access 0, 1 and 2.

Now you'll just add a listener to the child of the Database reference that you are looking for. In the case below, we're asking for the value that has the key "0".

```
public void checkFunction() {

    private FirebaseDatabase mRef;
    //String variable to store whatever value we're looking for
    String mName = "";

    //Our reference knows only "Users" and all of its children
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");  

    //Adding a listener for the value associated with the user key "0"
    mRef.child("0").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //In this case, "shalom" will be stored in mName
            mName = (String) snapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Hope this makes it easier to understand whats going on.

It's hard to answer any better than that without knowing more, but I suspect you need to reconsider the structure of your database. Maybe something more inline with the structure below, where the *RandomUserIdsHere* are the auto generated uids assigned to each user when registering with Firebase Auth.

```
todofirebaseapp-4c83d{
               "Users" :{
                   "*RandomUserIdsHere*" : {
                         "FirstName" : "Joe",
                         "LastName" : "Bloggs",
                          "Age" : "30"
                     }
                   "*AnotherRandomUserIdsHere*" : {
                         "FirstName" : "Jane",
                         "LastName" : "Doe",
                          "Age" : "21"
                     }
                   "*AnotherRandomUserIdsHere*" : {
                         "FirstName" : "John",
                         "LastName" : "Doe",
                          "Age" : "47"
                     }
              }

}
```

In this case, the DatabaseReference would look a little different. We'd be passing in the uid like so.

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid;
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("todofirebaseapp-4c83d").child("Users").child(uid);
```

**Edit:** To correct my inability to spel.

Comment: First, im sorry that my question is without much details im new at all those stuffs and i hope my next questions will be writed better.  You asked what im trying to do but im trying just this little thing of retriving a single String.  Also in your solution im fighting with the problem of getting the String out of the onDataChange , because it says " varieble 'mName' is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final" .  I cant add to mName final or it will do me an error when i will try to do the getValue.  Can you please help me solve this last thing?

Comment: Hi, You don't need to assign it as final. Create it at the top of the class and declare as a private string.
I included it in the example code in order for you to see whats going on, as I figured it might be unclear of I left you to assume it should be a class accessible variable.
The database reference  should also be created at the top of the class, and not inside a function/method.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all download google-services.json file from your project settings.
2. Paste it in app directory of the app.
3. Write below code in your onCreate or function where you want to retrieve your data.

   private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
   // ...
   mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

   //Read values
   ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
           Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue("userId");
           // ...
       }

   @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           // Getting Post failed, log a message
           Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
           // ...
       }
   };
   mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);

Comment: I tried , but i dont want to use post class , i just wanted to get a String And it dont understund the `getValue("Users")`.

Comment: Users is the jsonobject from the json, above code is working. I'm working on it from last 1 yeae

Comment: Threre is a solution without to use Post class?